# Forcing HTTPS for a specific url

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ssl

How, in htaccess, can you force a URL to be HTTPS at the beginning even if it was specified at HTTP?

E.g. the follwoing urls

```
/subscribe/spanish
/subscribe/english
```

I'm assumming there is some kind of regex that can be used with /subscribe at the start?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use following rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^subscribe/ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE,NC]
```

This will force https if:

- URI starts with `/subscribe/`
- URI has http scheme